if any of these guys are good
a. If any of these guys are good for the job, take him.
b. If any one of these guys is good for the job, take him.
Can't these sentences have two meanings:

If there is one person among these guys who is good for the job, take that person.

If any of these guys can do the job, then take this one. (Here 'him' would refer to a specific person being pointed at.)


Consider:
a1. If any of these guys are good for the job, take Tom.
b1. If any one of these guys is good for the job, take Tom.
Many thanks

What if the one that's good is not Tom? Why do we take him then?

Could you give more information about what your question is or what you're confused about? It's not quite clear here what you are asking

Thank you both very much. The question is about ambiguity. I think 'If any of them are good' could mean either that 'if there is one of them that's good' and also 'if all of them are good'. If all of them are good, take Tom. You say any of them are good, well, if any of them are good, then take Tom.

(a) doesn't make sense to me - 'if any are' implies that more than one could be selected, so it doesn't go with 'take him'.

@KateBunting - exactly! Since 'any' can be singular or plural, you merely need to select the right verb and pronoun forms.

Is "his one" a typo for "this one"?

The second one does not make any logical sense. If you say 'If any one of these people can do the job, take him' (pointing at someone), that's crazy. What if the 'one person' who can do the job is not him? There are plenty of made-up sentences that seem 'ambiguous', but they are very often things that no-one would ever say in real life.

If the 'any one' of 'these guys' that can do the job is Joe, or Bill, why would (or should) the other person take Tom? This question is a silly one.

The 2nd meaning is possible, but based on context, would take a lot of hints to happen
Suppose that you mean you want to take a specific person, then:

There is no reason to subject others to a test along with him
If the specific person is already guaranteed to go and just needs to form a group, there is no reason to mention him in the sentence
If the test is just an excuse (e.g. he's already admitted and just need a formality test), there is no reason to mention others

If I read that sentence, I'd assume the first intended meaning to be "take anyone who qualifies", and will only shift to another if there are strong hints (such as directly pointing at a specific person)

It's a bit silly, but yes.  The reference of "him" needs to be understood by context. The obvious context is speech that preceded it. That context would favour the first interpretation of "him".  But if you are pointing at someone that is a different context.
There's nothing fancy, and nothing special about English here.

Joe is a student, and {pointing at Harry} he is studying maths.


Joe ist Student und {zeigt auf Harry} er studiert Mathematik.

In both cases the pronoun is understood in the context of the gesture to refer to Harry.
